# Merge Data into Table from Named Stage

Tags: merge, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am having trouble merging data into Snowflake table from a internal named stage. I did refer to the knowledge base [article](https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/how-to-perform-a-mergeupsert-from-a-flat-file-staged-on-s3?t=1581602726978).

```
My code is pasted below and the error is also pasted below.
```

Code:

```
MERGE INTO ORDERS TGT 
USING 
    (
        SELECT $1::NUMBER                             o_orderkey,
               $2::NUMBER                             o_custkey,
               $3::STRING                             o_orderstatus,
               $4::FLOAT                              o_totalprice,
               TO_DATE($5::VARCHAR, 'YYYY-MM-DD')     O_ORDERDATE,
               $6::STRING                             o_orderpriority,
               $7::STRING                             o_clerk,
               $8::STRING                             o_shippriority,
               $9::STRING                             o_comment
        from '@STG_IVP_REF_BULK_DATA_MIGRATION/ORDERS/Snowflake_DB_Data_12-Feb-2020_02-59-50-PM.csv.gz'
        (file_format = (field_delimiter = '|'))
    )SRC
ON SRC.O_ORDERKEY = TGT.O_ORDERKEY
WHEN MATCHED 
THEN
    UPDATE SET TGT.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()::TIMESTAMP_NTZ
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN
    INSERT (o_orderkey, o_custkey, o_orderstatus, o_totalprice, O_ORDERDATE, o_orderpriority, o_clerk, o_shippriority, o_comment)
    VALUES (o_orderkey, o_custkey, o_orderstatus, o_totalprice, O_ORDERDATE, o_orderpriority, o_clerk, o_shippriority, o_comment);
```

Error Output:

```
SQL Error [2018] [22023]: SQL compilation error:
Invalid argument [2=>[unresolved function: "="](FILE_FORMAT, [unresolved function: "="](FIELD_DELIMITER, '|'))] for table function. Table function argument is required to be a constant.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you create a file_format object for defining the delimiter as '|', and use it on your query? For example:

```
CREATE FILE FORMAT myformat TYPE = 'CSV' FIELD_DELIMITER = '|';


MERGE INTO ORDERS TGT 
USING 
    (
        SELECT $1::NUMBER                             o_orderkey,
               $2::NUMBER                             o_custkey,
               $3::STRING                             o_orderstatus,
               $4::FLOAT                              o_totalprice,
               TO_DATE($5::VARCHAR, 'YYYY-MM-DD')     O_ORDERDATE,
               $6::STRING                             o_orderpriority,
               $7::STRING                             o_clerk,
               $8::STRING                             o_shippriority,
               $9::STRING                             o_comment
        from '@STG_IVP_REF_BULK_DATA_MIGRATION/ORDERS/Snowflake_DB_Data_12-Feb-2020_02-59-50-PM.csv.gz'
        (file_format => myformat)
    )SRC
ON SRC.O_ORDERKEY = TGT.O_ORDERKEY
WHEN MATCHED 
THEN
    UPDATE SET TGT.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()::TIMESTAMP_NTZ
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN
    INSERT (o_orderkey, o_custkey, o_orderstatus, o_totalprice, O_ORDERDATE, o_orderpriority, o_clerk, o_shippriority, o_comment)
    VALUES (o_orderkey, o_custkey, o_orderstatus, o_totalprice, O_ORDERDATE, o_orderpriority, o_clerk, o_shippriority, o_comment);
```

When querying the data from staging, you need to use FILE_FORMAT objects:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/querying-stage.html#query-syntax-and-parameters